# Constants module, ran once

Tags: python

So I'm building a constants module that stores in dict some strings:

```
class Labels():
     Table = {"value1" : "value1" , ...}
     
     Table_2 = {"value1" : "value1" , ...}
```

Now to improve the module I want to retrieve the constants automatically, to reduce future maintenance. For this I use a method called get_constants() which returns a dict with the constants. So the module will be:

```
class Labels():
 Table = get_constants("1")

 Table_2 = get_constants("2")
```

Now to improve the performance I only want the methods to be ran once and not every time I need a constant. Any sugestions?

Comment: This is a class, not a module. Your attribute assignments are syntax errors: a dict uses `{...}`, not `[...]`.

Comment: If you are only defining `Labels` once, then `get_constants` *will* only be called once per attribute. Even if you import the module containing `Labels` multiple times, only the first import actually *creates* the module (and thus the class); future imports see that the module has already been imported and stored in `sys.modules`.

Comment: And `get_constants` is executed when the class is defined, not when you access the attribute. That is, `Labels.Table` does not call `get_constants("1")`; it returns the `dict` stored in memory that was created when `get_constants` was called while `Labels` was being defined.

Comment: What is ``get_constants("1")`` and such supposed to do? It looks like you already store constants and ``dict`` lookups are already very fast – adding an intermediate getter is likely to *slow down* things.

Comment: @chepner Yes exactly, I am importing later on. Ok, thx for the explanation!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi get_constants() does a API GET request, retrieves the keys from the JSON response and then returns them in a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Labels:
    Test = get_constants("1")
    Test2 = get_constants("2")
```

already does what you want. When you import the module *the first time*, the class `Labels` will be defined as part of defining the module, and as part of the process of defining the class, `get_constants` will be called and its *return value* will be saved as the value of each class attribute.

If you import the module more than once, the import system detects that it already exists (a reference to it is saved in `sys.module`), so it will not be defined a second time.

Later, when you *access* the class attributes, the `dict`s will already be there.